# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>

Tags: linq, where-clause, datarow

I have this piece of code:

```
Db.DbDataSet.Tables["costallocations"]
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Where(Row => Row.Field<long>("callocid") == OldCostAllocationId)[0]["newid"]
```

And I'm getting the error above. In my opinion, it should work. How can I access the first record of the result set? There will be always only one hit, btw, therefore I use the 0.

Comment: `EnumerableRowCollection<TRow>` does not have an indexer. Try with `First()`.

Comment: There is no First() extension. At the end, I resolved it with a for cycle.